# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Schedule_swimmingscore

Tags: django, django-models

So, This is my model SwimmingScore:

```
class SwimmingScore(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team_swimming', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gold = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    silver = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    bronze = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    fourth = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    points = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

I used the command *python manage.py makemigrations* and then *python manage.py migrate* . So when i am opening admin through website, it is showing "no such table", i have confirmed it through *python manage.py dbshell >.table* , there is actually no table forSwimmingScore, but when i am re-runnung *python manage.py makemigrations*, it is behaving as if model is actually migrated, for crosscheck , i have altered one field, and on terminal it is actually showing it:

```
Migrations for 'Schedule':
  Schedule/migrations/0003_auto_20180707_0815.py
    - Alter field team on swimmingscore
```

Whats the standard procedure to handle such cases? I am totally stuck in it. I am using sqlite3 as database in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting dbsqlite file and all the migration files and then running *python manage.py makemigrations* and then *python manage.py migrate* worked for me. Actually this type of error happens when we use some previous used model names which we have deleted , but they still have a table in sqlite , so django cannot let the new table formed, so the error "no table found" can be there. Thanks :)